# Minor upgrade fails on removing files

Tags: .net, installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3

Desktop application with WIX installer. Version A of the application contains the following files: a.dll, b.dll, c.dll.
Version B contains files: b.dll, c.dll, d.dll.
After performing minor upgrade from A to B version, no files are replaced. I think that problem is with a.dll file which is present in A version and is not in B.

Can't we remove files during minor upgrade?
When a.dll is attached to B version, upgrade ends up successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This is a violation of the component rules. Only Major Upgrades can remove a component.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/changing-the-product-code

**The product code must be changed if any of the following are true for the update:**

- A component is removed from an existing feature.

That said, there is a workaround.  Make the component as Transitive = True and give the component a condition that will always evaluate to false.  You must still include the file in the MSI but it can be a zero byte file if you'd like.

This will "puncture" the component.  As far as MSI is concerned the component still exists and the rules aren't broken but the component will be removed from the machine because it reevaluates the component condition and requests it to be removed.